# Does location affect the PSI lab test

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am curious if your location when running a lab test in page speed insights determines the version of the site that is tested. For instance some sites might implement cookie consent in certain regions, would a test on page speed insights account for this if the test is ran from a region that does not use the cookie consent?

Would the version of the site tested not include the consent modal since the region we are testing from doesn't use the consent modal?

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed Insights lab tests are [run from one of three locations](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#what-device-and-network-conditions-does-lighthouse-use-to-simulate-a-page-load)

> PageSpeed also runs in a Google datacenter that can vary based on network conditions, you can check the location that the test was by looking at the Lighthouse Report's environment block:
> PageSpeed will report running in one of: North America, Europe, or Asia.

Typically it takes the location nearest you.

So  yes, if you serve different data based on where it's coming from, then it will reflect that (depending on the accuracy of your detection).